# How can I make method "businessLogic" return not void but String and return "words" for further usage in Main.class?

Tags: java

It's method which I want to change from "void" to "String".

```
public static void businessLogic(String[] words) {
    for (String word : words) {

        char[] arrayWordsInChar = word.toCharArray();

        int wordLength = word.length();

        for (int i = 0, j = wordLength - 1; i < j; ) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(arrayWordsInChar[i]))
                i++; 
        else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(arrayWordsInChar[j]))
                j--;
            else
                swapLetters(arrayWordsInChar, i++, j--);
        }
System.out.print(arrayWordsInChar);
        System.out.print(" ");


    }
    // possible return...
}
```

When I am trying to set return "arrayWordsInChar", IDEA doesn't see this variable...

Some more code:

```
public static void swapLetters(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

And the Main.Class :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

        businessLogic(words);
    // System.out.println(businessLogic(words));
}
}
```

Comment: `char[] arrayWordsInChar = word.toCharArray();` is scoped to your `for` loop, if you want to `return` it, you would need to declare it outside (above) your `for` loop so it is scoped to the `method`. Since you are dealing with multiple words via your char[] you will probably want to declare a Vector to add each word into for your return.

Comment: As an aside, using if statements without brackets is generally considered bad practice, and can very easily result in unintentional bugs.